# Edit Attribute of External Webpage on Client-Side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a program that can edit an attribute of a webpage automatically just like the chrome developer tools can do with changing around the code of a webpage on the client-side until it is refreshed. I have a web server running php that could possibly be utilized or I was wondering if a chrome extension running javascript could.

Basically, I want to change the attribute of a certain tag on a certain webpage automatically.

Edit: I want to change the source of an iframe tag to a different webpage.

Comment: You might have better luck getting your question answered if you were more specific. Rather than "certain tag" on "certain webpage", provide a specific, concrete example.

Comment: what's the point of such idea? You need inevitably specify certain attribute of certain node. Beforehand, you should manipulate the whole DOM tree of loaded webpage. Find some DOM parser. (Anyway built-in browser developer tools already do this in best way)